# Can both Mac OS and Windows (via Bootcamp) agree on a unique dropbox folder location?

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, partition, dropbox

I'm planning to install Windows 8 via Bootcamp. I want to know if it is possible to make a third partition to hold my dropbox folder for my both Mac and Windows dropbox instances? & If possible, what type of partition should I have so that both Mac OS and Windows become comfortable reading and writing to it?

p.s. I'm trying to avoid duplicate syncing and duplicate storage of the same dropbox content in my laptop.

Comment: The real concern is if the dropbox apps for the respective OSs pay attention to permissions and meta data the same way because each OS handles files in general differently. You shouldn't need to create a whole partition just for dropbox, just use a subfolder which is shared between them both.

Comment: Not direct answer to your question, but Parrallells 9 support accessing your dropbox form Virtual Machine without duplicating it.  Agree with @Andrew U.  could end with horrible mess if both Windows and Mac access the same database.

Comment: @Joop so do you think I should avoid doing this?

Comment: I have not tried it..   If you do it do it with some trial data 1st.   I would not try this with my real dropbox.  But then someone here might have experience doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an EXFAT partition. You can set a dropbox folder on an unique location, you'll save a lot of space and bandwidth with that.

Comment: @Farshid Andrew said "just use a subfolder" but that will be hard to share a subfolder on your case as natively, the filesystems are not compatible, be aware of that.